Trying to integrate a matrix that is a function of variable but ran into a problem I don´t know how to get around
I want to integrate over a matrix as a part of solving Schrödingers equation with a time dependent potential.
The matrix is composed of 4 8x8 matrices and scalar function. The first matrix describes a rotation denoted U in the code, the second matrix describes a scaling that is a function of time (eE in the code) and the third matrix a rotation (U_H in the code). It represents a change of basis to the eigenbase to perform the transformation. The fourth matrix consists of the eigenvectors and the coefficients to each eigenvector (a ket) and it should represent the inital guessed wave function (psi_0 in the code). The scalar function is describing the time dependent potential (V(t) in the code).
I want to integrate the matrix with the initial guessed wave function to compute a new wave function. Then i want to take the norm of the difference between the wave functions. I want to redo the integration of the matrix but with the previously calculated wave functions to get another new wave function and calculate the new norm. I want to do this process until the norm of the difference converge.
To do the integration I thought of integrating each element of the matrix with the use of scipy.integrate.quad. Since the matrix is time dependent I have used lambda functions to make the matrix into a function of the variable t. I then thought I could call for each of the element of the matrix to then integrate it, but it seems like it's not possible to do it. This part of the code:
tol = 10**(-5)                                                            #Set the tolerance
angfreq = pi/3                                                            #Set the angular frequency
error = 1                                                                 #Set initial error to get into while-loop
ti = 0                                                                    #Integration limits
tf = 1

c_0 = np.array([np.random.rand(len(eigenvectors[0]))])                    #Initial guess coefficients
psi_0 = norm(c_0*eigenvectors)                                            #Initial wave function guess
psi = np.empty(np.shape(psi_0))                                           #Construct next wave function to be calculated

while tol < error:
    func = lambda t, psi_0: U@eE(t, tf)@U_H@psi_0*V(t, angfreq)             #The composite matrix that is a function of t
    for row in range(len(psi_0[0])):                                        #Get into row
        for column in range(len(psi_0[0])):                                 #Get into column
            psi[row][column] = quad(func[row][column], ti, tf)              #Accesss the specific element (row and column) in psi-vector and change it to a new value, the new value will be the value of the integral of the corresponding element 
    error = np.linalg.norm(psi-psi_0)
    psi_0 = norm(psi)

I get the following error: "'function' object is not subscriptable".I don't know how I could get around it.

On the line psi[row][column] = quad(func[row][column], ti, tf), did you intend to call the function func rather than subscript it?

I want to call the element of the matrix, but since the matrix has the variable t in it, I thought i might do the matrix into a function. But I'm doing it wrong here. However, I can't come up with a way to access the elements (that is a function of t) of the matrix. I intend to call the function and thus the matrix...and the elements of the matrix.

You can't integrate a numpy array ('matrix').  It's elements are numbers, not functions.  quad takes a scalar function, f(x, *args), where x is a scalar value that quad varies between the limits, returns a scalar value.  (args are extra variables that quad does not fiddle with.)

func as you define it takes 2 arguments, t and psi_0.  U, eE etc are unknown (to us).  We can't tell what func(1,2) produces.  In any case you can't treat the func itself as though it were a list or array.

But if I can treat it as an array why do I get an error saying: "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable"? U, eE etc are just matrices (2d numpy array), eE returns "expm(-1j*(tf-t)*E) " which is a matrix.

The result of running func(0,0) may be an array, and is subscriptable.  But func by itself is NOT an array.  It is a function, and basic Python will tell you that a function is not subscriptable.  numpy (and scipy) runs with in Python  They add an array class and functions, but never change the basic syntax.

This alternate block might work.
It won't be very efficient, since, for each row, column, t, func is called and returns an array, with only one element being passed on through to quad.
row, column, psi_0 are globals for foo, but then U, U_H, angfreq are globals for func, and eE and V are externally defined functions.
    func = lambda t, psi_0: U@eE(t, tf)@U_H@psi_0*V(t, angfreq)  
    for row in range(len(psi_0[0])):                                        
        for column in range(len(psi_0[0])):
            foo = lambda t: func(t, psi_0)[row, column]                              
            psi[row, column] = quad(foo, ti, tf)              
    error = np.linalg.norm(psi-psi_0)
    psi_0 = norm(psi)

